# How can I use two conditions in Do While loop in Java

Tags: java, loops, conditional-statements, boolean-expression

```
do{
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String value = scan.nextLine();
}while(!value.equals("example")/* need another condition here*/);
```

I want to put two(or more) conditions here, any one of them should be true to stop looping. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you heard of the boolean operators yet? If not, do google them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Boolean operators**

**AND** (`&&`)

```
p   q   p && q
T   T   T
T   F   F
F   T   F
F   F   F
```

**OR** (`||`)

```
p   q   p || q
T   T   T
T   F   T
F   T   T
F   F   F
```

So, to use it in your conditions.

```
if (x != 9 && x != 10) { ... }

if (x == 0 || x == 5) { ... }
```

Comment: @melpomene Why have you changed the comparison operators?

Comment: @Tom I changed `x != 0 || x != 5` to `x == 0 || x == 5` because the former is always true (and is a somewhat common logic error that I didn't want to perpetuate in an example).

Comment: Thanks Uma, It helped me :D

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using && or || between conditions? I'm new and I hope I'm not telling the obvious.

... while(!value.equals("example") && otherCondition || !found)...

Answer (score 0):

The condtion s: cond1, cond2, cond3, .... condN.

"any one of them should be true" = (cond1==true && cond2==true && cond3==true && ... condN==true)

I your code it will be like:
stop looping = ! before all the expresstion

do{

}while(!(cond1==true && cond2==true && cond3==true && ... condN==true));

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to stop the loop wenn either one of the statements is true or both of them are true, you need to use the boolean or operator "||".

If both of the statements should be true to stop the loop, you need to use boolena and operator "&&"